# UIPicker for month and year. Getting years dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, uipickerview

I am trying to make a picker with month and year only (for credit card expiration date). After searching around, it seems that using a custom UIPicker would be the best option.

My question is, is there a way to get the array for years dynamically, without having to hardcode all of the upcoming years? I have been looking around, but can't seem to find an answer.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extract the current year from an `NSDate` object. Then build the year list using a loop.

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
int year = [comps year];

NSMutableArray *years = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int y = year; y < year + 20; y++) {
    [years addObject:@(y)];
}
```

Change the `20` for however many years you want in the list.